# Java can't get object to cast from file to arraylist

Tags: java, object, arraylist, casting

I'm trying to load an object in from a file. I first create the file by saving an object to it. If I save only one object to a file I can get it loaded in by casting the object into a variable stead of an arraylist. But if I try to cast mulitple objects into an arraylist I keep getting errors. I sometimes will get this:

> animalkingdom.AnimalBuild; local class incompatible: stream classdesc
>   serialVersionUID = 8814442576780984798, local class serialVersionUID =
>   -7073710162342893881

or this

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   animalkingdom.AnimalBuild cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList   at
>   animalkingdom.AnimalKingdom.readFile(AnimalKingdom.java:146)  at
>   animalkingdom.AnimalKingdom.main(AnimalKingdom.java:123) Java Result:
>   1

write function

```
  // function to write object to file
       public static void writeToFile(ArrayList<AnimalBuild> a) throws    IOException  { 
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream (new FileOutputStream("animal2.txt"));

        for (AnimalBuild s : a) { // loop through and write objects to file. 
            oos.writeObject(s);
        }
    }
```

read function

```
  // function to read from file
     public static void readFile() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("animal2.txt"));

       @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") 
       ArrayList<AnimalBuild> animalList = (ArrayList<AnimalBuild>)ois.readObject(); // casting object

        Iterator it = animalList.iterator();

        while(it.hasNext()) {
         String obj = (String)it.next();
         System.out.println(obj);
    }      
}
```

Animal Build

```
class AnimalBuild implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 8814442576780984798L;
//private static final long serialVersionUID = -12049485535619732L;


public String Animaltype, Species, Color;
public AnimalBuild (String animaltype , String species, String color )
{
    this.Animaltype = animaltype;
    this.Species = species;
    this.Color = color;
}

public String getType() {
    return this.Animaltype;
}
public String getSpecies() {
    return this.Species;
}
public String getColor() {
    return this.Color;
}

public String setType(String newType) {
    return (this.Animaltype=newType);
}

public String setSpecies(String newSpecies) {
    return (this.Species=newSpecies);
}

public String setColor(String newColor) {
    return (this.Color=newColor);
}

public String toString ()
{
    return "\n\n Animal Type: " + this.Animaltype + "\n Species: "  + this.Species + "\n Color: " + this.Color + "\n";
}
}
```

Comment: you are writing each individual object to the file.  if you want to write the List, then just write the List.

Comment: You can't write out a bunch of separate objects and then expect to read them back in as an `ArrayList`.

Comment: I'm storying all my objects in an arraylist, and I want to be able to save the arraylist full of objects to a file and than load them back in.  I'm not sure Im following what you guys are saying.

Answer (score 1):

When you serialize data you need to read it in a compatible manner to how it was written.  You are writing each element individually so to read this you would need to read them individually.

However, writing a list is simpler.

```
try (ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("animal2.txt"))) {
    oos.writeObject(a);
}
```

To read the list

```
List<AnimalBuild> animalList;
try (ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("animal2.txt"))) {
     animalList = (List<AnimalBuild>) ois.readObject(); // casting object
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped and what you said makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 0):

Read the object one by one then add to list. Just reverse the way you write the object. Check sample code below:

```
List<AnimalBuild> animalList  = new ArrayList<AnimalBuild>();
Object obj = null;
while ((obj = ois.readObject()) != null) {
    if (obj instanceof AnimalBuild) {
    AnimalBuild ab = (AnimalBuild) obj;
    animalList .add(ab);
    }
}
```

You could write the entire list as one object to the file and then read it back as same object rather than writing one by one.